Evaluating the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n n}{n^2+1}}$
I am trying to solve the integral
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{e^x +1}\mathrm{d} x
\end{align}
and I have encountered this sum:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n n}{n^2+1}}
\end{align}
I was unable to solve it using the residue theorem or other techniques. Thanks in advance.

Do you have any reason to believe that either the integral or the sum have a closed form?

Try reiman integral technique

@jjagmath WolframAlpha gives me a closed form in terms of polygamma functions.

@user170231 that does not work in this case since the additional factor of n is missing in the expansion of csch(x)

To evaluate the sum decompose the summand into partial fractions – complexly:
$$\frac i2\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{1+in}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{1-in}\right)$$
Now use (6) on MathWorld's page on the digamma function to get the result:
$$\frac14(\psi(-i/2)+\psi(i/2)-\psi((1-i)/2)-\psi((1+i)/2)$$
